# PHP ''Dynamic'' Checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, database, checkbox

I've tried to create list of users. In front of every user i have tried to place check box to check attendance. 
Unfortunately i don't succeed to create a "dynamic" one. Can somebody explain to me how to achive that type of list ? (to print checkbox infront of every registred user and print results)

Here is my code :

```
            <?php

                echo '<h2>Students:</h2>';

                $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_type = 'user' ";

                $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

                if ($result){
                    while($user = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo $user['username'], '</br>';
                    }
                }

            ?>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line `echo $user['username'], '</br>';` with:

```
$username = $user['username'] ;
echo "<input type=checkbox name='user' value='$username'>$username<br>" ;
```

The first line saves the username to a variable which can be more easily accessed from within the `echo` on the next line. The second line will print an html checkbox for each username, with a common name of 'user' and a value of the username for each one.

Comment: Thank you Rob. Can i sumbit this to output file or something like that?

Comment: Are you familiar with html forms? Put the code above within form tags and add a submit button. The action page will receive the state of the checkboxes.